# SOAP WSDL sequence definition - one argument or many?

Tags: soap, wsdl, wsdl2java

### Problem/Intro

I have not really used SOAP in very many years due to REST.

I have the following definition in a `WSDL` file:

```
<xs:complexType name="findByIdentifier">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="arg0" type="xs:long"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
```

The code method generated from `WSDL2Java` is

```
findByIdentifier(
        @WebParam(name = "arg0", targetNamespace = "")
        long arg0
    )
```

The requirements specify that I should submit an array of long.

I see also that `maxOccurs` and `minOccurs` are missing from the WSDL.

### Question

How should I modify the WSDL file I have in my project in order to have a method generated that takes an array?

If I should not hack the WSDL should I do something else like a custom implementation via an extended class or a custom client implementation (defeats the purpose of generating code)?

Comment: You have seen that ``maxOccurs`` and ``minOccurs`` are missing inside the wsdl? So why not just add them?

Comment: @jmattheis Well, the project manager says that would cause incompatibilities with the client's webservice. We did download the WSDL from their server. I've tried adding an `unbounded` max and am trying it.

Comment: BTW where came that requirement from that you should submit an array of long? The wsdl specifies that there is only one ``long`` arg so the rest server will only accept a ``long`` and not an array of that? Or is the wsdl faulty?

Comment: @ jmattheis It seems there is a discrepancy between the details outlined in the documentation/useCases by the client and their WSDL. I hacked the WSDL and am trying the call to see what will happen.

Comment: @jmattheis I tried sending an arraylist of long. I received only one element back. I will try changing the response definition to be `anytype` as well in case that plays a role. It turns out changing the type causes the same object to be returned. The only solution is for them to change their webservice implementation & WSDL or for me to use a for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution as proposed by the team leader was to use a `loop` since the WSDL and the actual webservice behavior show that an `array` is not supported for an argument.